# Force.com IDE unable to save code on server

Tags: force.com, community, salesforce1-app

It is very annoying that Force.com IDE unable to save code on server. And the worst thing is after triggering save to server option the code is reverted back as it wasn't there at first point. Any solution will be helpful. I'm newbie might don't know the tools of trade. Please guide.

Comment: Hi Kisan, welcome to SFSE! It would be helpful to know what version of the IDE you're using & what OS. Are you using it installed in Eclipse? If so, what version of Eclipse? The more details you provide, the more helpful assistance you're likely to get. If you haven't already done so, please visit the [Help] and take the tour to learn how to get the most from SF.SE.

Comment: If you are just starting with Force.com the simplest way to work is to just use the "Setup" UI and the "Developer Console". And then move to the Force.com IDE (or one of the alternatives as the Force.com IDE remains more troublesome than it should be) when you want to e.g. introduce version control.

Comment: @crmprogdev I've Eclipse Luna on windows XP. For Force.com IDE I'm using this [link](http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42).

Answer (score 2):

Lately I was having issues with Force.com IDE, however after upgrade to the latest Java Version it was working ok again.

To save code on server directly when you click Save or press ctrl+s you need to have de activate the work offline mode. This way every time you try to save it will be send to server.

Another little thing is that sometimes maybe the class in server has changes that eclipse doesn't have, then if you refresh for server your project when you start your work then your project will be ready to work with.

I hope this help.

Thanks,
Carolina.

Comment: Thanks Carolina. I'm updating my java right now just to check if it is the reason. Further things you explained I understand. In my case it is just a field's attributes. Every time it done with saving on server processing. Code reverted back to the original as it was before. 

 `<nameField>
        <displayFormat>MR - {0000}</displayFormat>
        <label>Mileage Report Number</label>
        <type>AutoNumber</type>
    </nameField>`
I tried to add <startingNumber>1</startingNumber> but failed.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for save to not work. I have listed down a few below:

1. Your code is not latest. i.e. If differs from the code you have online.
2. The change that you are trying to make is not allowed or has some error.
3. 'Build Automatically' under Project menu is not checked.
4. You are working offline.

HTH

Thanks,
Malay